# Return time mysql php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm having the following trouble. I have a table in MySql database with some time columns, 2 for each day of the week. When I try to read the data from the table from a php query I have an error, but if I copy the query and execute it into the phpMyAdmin the query gives me results.

The message of the error is

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in...

I try to format the result with date_format(**here comes the result value**,'H:i:s') but it doesn't works.

Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
var area_id = $('#slkt_areas').val();
    if(area_id != 0)
    {
        $.post("libs/php/jquery/cfg/get_distinct_areas_info.php",{
            area: area_id
            },
            function(data)
            {
                if(data!= '')
                {
                    var resultado = data.split('&:&');
                    var largo = resultado.length;
                    var link_genera_qr='';
                    var contador = 0;
                        $('#txtbx_nombre').val(resultado[contador]); //nombre
                        $('#txtbx_abbref').val(resultado[contador+1]); //letra
                        $('#txtbx_rut option[value='+ resultado[contador+3] +']').attr("selected",true); //rut obligatorio
                        $('#icons_final_imagen').html('<center><img src="' + resultado[contador+4] + '" alt="" style="height:80px;"/></center>');
                        $('#txtbxhid_iconsimage').val(resultado[contador+4]);
                        $('#txtbx_cantmodulos').val(resultado[contador+5]);
                        $('#txtbxhid_id').val(resultado[contador+6]);
                        $('#rel_user_qr').html(resultado[contador+8]); // url
                        $('#slkt_status option[value=' + resultado[contador+7] +']').attr("selected",true);//estado
                        $('#mon_start').val(contador+9);
                        $('#mon_end').val(contador+10);
                        $('#tue_start').val(contador+11);
                        $('#tue_end').val(contador+12);
                        $('#wed_start').val(contador+13);
                        $('#wed_end').val(contador+14);
                        $('#thu_start').val(contador+15);
                        $('#thu_end').val(contador+16);
                        $('#fri_start').val(contador+17);
                        $('#fri_end').val(contador+18);
                        $('#sat_start').val(contador+19);
                        $('#sat_end').val(contador+20);
                        $('#sun_start').val(contador+21);
                        $('#sun_end').val(contador+22);
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

PHP

```
$cns="CALL sp_get_area_dataById(".$_POST['area'].")";
    $accion ="";
    $id=0;
    foreach($db->retorna($cns) as $a)
    {
        $accion = date_format($a->mon_end,'H:i:s');

        *$accion .= $a->name."&:&".$a->abbref."&:&"; //0,1
        $accion.= $a->imagen."&:&".$a->rut_obligatorio.'&:&'; //2,3
        $accion.=$a->icon_image."&:&".$a->qty_modulos."&:&".$a->id."&:&"; //4,5,6
        $accion.=$a->status_id."&:&";//7
        $id=$a->id;
        $accion.=date_format($a->1_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->1_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//lunes// 8,9
        $accion.=date_format($a->2_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->2_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//martes // 10,11
        $accion.=date_format($a->3_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->3_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//miercoles //12,13
        $accion.=date_format($a->4_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->4_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//jueves //14, 15
        $accion.=date_format($a->5_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->5_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//viernes // 16,17
        $accion.=date_format($a->6_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->6_end,'H:i:s')."&:&";//sabado //17,18
        $accion.=date_format($a->7_start,'H:i:s')."&:&".date_format($a->7_end,'H:i:s');//domingo //19,20

    }
    echo $accion;
```

Stored Procedure in MySql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_get_area_dataById`(IN var_id int)
BEGIN
select 
    `id`,
    `name`,
    abbref,
    imagen,
    rut_obligatorio,
    icon_image,
    qty_modulos,
    status_id,
    mon_start as 1_start,
    mon_end as 1_end,
    tue_start as 2_start,
    tue_end as 2_end,
    wed_start as 3_start,
    wed_end as 3_end,
    thu_start as 4_start,
    thu_end as 4_end,
    fri_start as 5_start,
    fri_end as 5_end,
    sat_start as 6_start,
    sat_end as 6_end,
    sun_start as 7_start,
    sun_end as 7_end
from
    areas
where
    id= var_id;
END
```

this is the retorna method:

```
public function retorna($qString){
        $this->qString = $qString;
        $this->conectar();
        $data = array();
        $this->resultado = $this->ejecutar($qString);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->resultado))
            $data[]= $row;
            $this->cerrar();
        return $data;
    }
```

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does your PHP query look like, and are you mixing mysql with mysqli statements?

Comment: hummm... I have attached the code of a demo query.

Comment: can you post your code for retorna method?

Comment: Yes. I update my question with the methods

Comment: It looks like you might also have sql injection vulnerability in your code, independent of other issues.

Comment: yes, I'm working on validating a number in the $_Post